# Rationale for expression “Fixer-upper”  

Tags: expressions

I have encountered the expression *fixer-upper*:

> A fixer-upper is a real-estate property that will require maintenance work     (redecoration, reconstruction or redesign) though it usually can be lived in     as it is.

But why is it called *fixer-upper*? I imagine the expression means that ‘fixing’ will ‘up’ the value of the property, but does it relate to other similar expressions with the same double-word construction?

Comment: There's [shaker-upper](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shaker-upper) (someone who shakes things up), which is common enough to get into Wiktionary, and I believe there are a number of other similar expressions in informal use in the U.S.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My first guess is that it's because the property needs to be *fixed up* or *requires* a "fixer-upper", i.e., somebody who can fix it up. [Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/fixer-upper.html) suggests something similar:

> What we now think of as a 'fixer-upper' comes to us from the USA as a colloquial term for **'something that needs fixing up'**. The first mention of this in print appears to be an advertisement for a house, in The Los Angeles Times, October 1948:
>
> [image]
>
> Prior to that coinage, a 'fixer-upper' was **'a person who fixes things'**.

Under 'Origin', [reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fixer-upper) simply states:

> fix up  + -er ,  pleonastically suffixed to both words

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *[fix up](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/fix-up)* means

> to clean, repair, or decorate something:
>
> *They take old furniture and fix it up.*
>
> *I'm going to fix up the house before my mother-in-law arrives.*

The term *[fixer-upper](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/fixer-upper)* refers to

> A house or other dwelling that is badly in need of repair, usually for sale at a low price.

A *fixer-upper* is a house that needs to be *fixed up*.